# After getting post request to node server from payment gateway, then how to direct to my ionic app

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, payu

I am using node as backend with ionic and integrated payment gateway. 
Steps i followed : -

- Sent post request to payment gateway with desired parameters.
- Received post request to my server after successful transaction.
- Now redirected flow from server to ionic app with localhost:8100
  Here is something, i have been stuck up. How to redirect the flow from server to ionic app after publishing because here i don't know what URL i need to use to open the desired page of my app in mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

In your node server you can redirect to specified URI like this:

```
response.writeHead(303, {
  'Location': 'path.html'
});
response.end();
```

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx)

Comment: Yes I can if it is a web page, but i am using it in ionic android app and while debugging i gave access to port 8100 through chrome inspect, but after published  that wouldn't work. So let me know what path i need to put to open the ionic app in android phone.

Answer (score 0):

After looking a lot of resources, I found a plugin named 'custom-Url-scheme' that helped me to resolve this issue.
Here is the git repository - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme